# how to authorize get request with bearer token?

Tags: api, https, request, postman

I am trying to use Transferwise api.

GET https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates
my token is `efdc55d1-3e58-4223-8d8e-402fe189a88d`

i get this error message over and over again :

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "baf58c02-e7ca-45b2-950a-44d6a39f851e"
}
```

I use Insomnia and Postman.
How I can get information from that link? sorry I started working with apis today and maybe my question is bad.

Answer (score 3):

The reason u get this message all the time is pretty simple: `u don't have account at:` *https://sandbox.transferwise.tech/register*

If u replace the URL

- from: *https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates*
- to: *https://api.transferwise.com/*
  it will be working sufficiently if your API token is not expired yet, and passed correctly.

I'm using curl as well and taking u'r example it looks like:
`curl -X GET https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates -H "Authorization: Bearer efdc55d1-3e58-4223-8d8e-402fe189a88d"`

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you can either add a request header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <Your token>
```

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#configuring-request-headers

Or use the `Auth` tab in the *Request Builder* and select the `Bearer Token` helper, which will add the Request Header for you.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/#bearer-token

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use:

```
GET https://api.transferwise.com/v1/rates
```

In order to use GET https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates you have to register on https://sandbox.transferwise.tech/register

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).